# Problems with running node or npm command in linux

Tags: node.js, linux, angular-cli

I have a problem that appeared to me as of today, I was working without any problem when suddenly I started to get the following error when trying to start my angular project, it does not let me execute the node or npm command

```
/snap/node/3190/bin/node: /snap/core/current/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.22' not found (required by /snap/node/3190/bin/node)
```

Does anyone know how to fix it, I'm on linux

Comment: Add the result of "ldd exe-pathname"

Comment: ldd: ./exe-pathname: File or directory does not exist

Comment: @LuisFernandoPrudencioCruz Which OS are you using?

Comment: ubuntu 20.04, @RachidK.

Comment: By "exe-pathname", I meant the name of your executable : /snap/node/3190/bin/node

Comment: Try this export PATH="$HOME/.npm-packages/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$HOME/.node/bin:$PATH"

Comment: @JatinMehrotra, that doesn't solve it

Comment: just saw your error the problem is with the version of your libstdc++.so.6 its old!.
just update your gcc to get new version of libstdc++.so.6